# How to search and select an object in JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, json, node.js

Consider a JSON like this:

```
[{
    "type": "person",
    "name": "Mike",
    "age": "29"
},
{
    "type": "person",
    "name": "Afshin",
    "age": "21"
},
{
    "type": "something_else",
    "where": "NY"
}]
```

I want to search in the JSON value with a key (for example `type='person'`) and then select a whole object of matched item in JSON. For example when I search for `type='person'` I expect this value:

```
[{
  "type": "person",
  "name": "Mike",
  "age": "29"
},
{
  "type": "person",
  "name": "Afshin",
  "age": "21"
}]
```

Because it's a really **big JSON value**, I don't want to do a brute-force search in all nodes, so I think the only way is using Regular Expressions but I don't know how can I write a Regex to match something like above.

I'm using **NodeJs** for the application.

Comment: That isn't JSON. Test it with http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [underscore.js#where](http://underscorejs.org/#where):

```
var results = _(yourObject).where({ type: 'person' })
```

If your data set is very very big [e.g. 10k or so], consider filtering / paginating stuff server side.

Comment: Thanks, seems a good solution but what if we have a nested object?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani if you expect an arbitrary nesting level, you need a richer data structure than a plain hash - e.g. an [ORM](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2).

Answer (score 1):

Plain javascript :

```
var results = dataset.filter(function(p) { 
    if(p.type == 'person') 
    return true; 
});
```

Comment: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'filter'

Comment: Are you sure that it's available in NodeJs?

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani - of course it's available in nodejs. are you actually working with an array as in your example above or is it wrapped in a container object?

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to scan multiple times through the collection, the following one time construction overhead might be of worth.

Use hashing based on values of type.Convert the current data structure to hash map.

var hashMap ={

};

hashMap['person'] =[{},{}];

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
$.grep(jsonarrayobj,function(n, i){
   if(n.type==="person")
{}
})
```